# a bounded real function that has finitely many discontinuities is Riemann integrable

Tags: analysis

Suppose that f is a bounded real function on [a, b] that has exactly k discontinuities $c_1, . . . , c_k$ in [a, b]. Show that f is Riemann integrable over [a, b].

My attempt:

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Put M = $sup |f(x)|$, let E be the set of these k discontinuities. Since E is finite, we can cover E by finitely many disjoint intervals $[u_j,v_j] \subset [a,b]$ such that the sum of the corresponding differences $v_j - u_j$ is less than $\epsilon$.

Furthermore, we can place these intervals in such a way that every point of $E \cap (a,b)$ lies in the interior of some $[u_j,v_j]$. **Comment:** This sentence is from Baby Rudin. I don't understand it. Why do we say it?

Remove the segments of $[u_j,v_j]$ from [a,b]. The remaining set K is compact. Hence, f is uniformly continuous on K, and there exists $\delta >0$ such that $f(s)-f(t)< \epsilon$ if $s \in K, t\in K, |s-t|<\delta$.

Now form a partition P = {$x_0, x_1,...,x_n$} of [a,b], as follows: Each $u_i$ occurs in P. Each $v_i$ occurs in P. No points of any segment $(u_j, u_j)$ occurs in P. If $x_{i-1}$ is not one of the $u_j$, then $\Delta x_i < \delta$. **Comment:** why $\Delta x_i < \delta$?

Comment: Does https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1216801/continuous-function-with-finitely-many-discontinuities-is-riemann-integral help?

Comment: That answer is not correct. It ignores the case when the discontinuous point happens to be the endpoint, a or b.